# Navbar covers my text when in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, navbar

So my issue is when in mobile mode my navbar covers my page context.
In other words parts of my text box that is on the page hides under the navbar.

My navbar CSS looks like this:

```
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  .navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
  
  .navbar-logo {
    color: #fff;
    justify-self: start;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .fa-typo3 {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60vw;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-links:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  
  .fa-bars {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .NavbarItems {
      position: relative;
    }

  
    .nav-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
  
    .nav-menu.active {
      background: #242222;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
    }
  
    .nav-links:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  
    .navbar-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(25%, 50%);
    }
  
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    .fa-times {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 80%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
  
    .nav-links-mobile:hover {
      background: #fff;
      color: #242424;
      transition: 250ms;
    }
  }
```

how can i stop this from happening ? The navbar works fine when its not in mobile mode.
Ill also add a picture to make it simple to see.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen link to your code? Also, you can try giving your navbar a bottom margin on mobile screens, but there can be a better solution - would help if you provide a CodePen link.

Comment: How do i do that i never used codePen?

Comment: It's normal when you use position absolute. You need to set margin-top for your text section

Comment: Go here https://codepen.io/pen/ , create an account, add your HTML, CSS and JavaScript code and share the link of the code.  Here's a guide to using CodePen https://www.bootstrapdash.com/how-to-use-codepen/

Comment: Is navbar always fixed on top..!? If so, please provide padding top for the container or the body that is holding text on the whole screen. (Add this padding only when navbar becomes fixed) .. or.. if it is absolute position as mentioned by @Pulse, please add margin-top...

Comment: Tried all of your suggestions nothing works. :(